# TableRow in ListView Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` which each row of which has the following
1. `TextView` 
2. `Button`

The `TextView`s can contain text of multiple lengths. So the list appears in an awkward way. I thought the way out will be to set each List item to a Table Row with 2 cells(TextView and Button) . Is there a way to do this? Or may be there is a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Relative Layout to display the row. In the Relative Layout put a button on the right with align parent right as true, and then set the TextView to the left of the Button to match parent. Also you could specify the TextView to be single line and ellipsize as true at end. This is just an example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="This is your textView with a very long text. I hope this code serves your problem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also use 2 TextViews, that totally depends upon the text that you want to display.

Comment: The textview is a file name, and the button is to save this file. This is what I initially did, but when the device screen is wide enough, the button aligns itself to the right and goes too far away from the text :-)

Comment: You can set the gravity of the TextView to be center, so that the button will stick to the right but the filename will be in the center so it wont look awkward! And you can add margins to the button and the layout to more beautify your list.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout and  it's weight attribute. More in official docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html